# ItemController does not work when we have a seperate controller for View

Tags: ember.js

Part of learning Ember.js I am trying to create a Table View in Ember, based on example by [Adam](http://hawkins.io/2013/07/table-sorting-with-ember/).

The issue I am facing is that if I create a seperate controller for the View and include an itemController for the Rows, ember gives following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookup' of null ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js:13933

When I debug this I find that in the following code :

```
controllerAt: function(idx, object, controllerClass) {
var container = get(this, 'container'),
    subControllers = get(this, '_subControllers'),
    subController = subControllers[idx];

if (!subController) {
  subController = container.lookup("controller:" + controllerClass, { singleton: false      });
```

The container is retrieved as `null`.

Whereas when it is run through ApplicationController, no such issue is there.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akashb/4bFdh/1/) Using ApplicationController for the View and another controller for itemController - Works Fine

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/idilix/2/edit)

in this the item Controller is specified as `{{#each controller itemController="tableRow"}}` and the controller is `App.TableRowController`

Here is a very similar [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uwuyus/1/edit), [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akashb/wEprA/2/) using a seperate TableViewController : 
The item controller is similarly specified as `{{#each controller itemController='tableRow'}`.
A seperate Controller for Table View is binded using : `{{view App.TableView controllerBinding="tableViewController"}}` and this tableViewController is specified as a property in ApplicationController as :

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
tableViewController: function() {
    var tc = Ember.get('App.TableViewController').create();
    tc.set('content',Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
                        content: Ember.A(tableData)})
            );
    return tc;
}.property()
});
```

But for some reason, the itemController does not work here.

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akashb/EMqGz/1/) Using seperate Controller for View, but without any itemController - this works fine

Is there anything I am missing in the controller ?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Ember most of the time you don't create objects directly, you declare the classes for things like controller, model, etc. And ember creates these objects using an IOC container. Avoid things like `Controller.create`. Similarly avoid directly `controllerBinding` instead use `needs`.

So, instead of providing a `controllerBinding` pass the content to be rendered by the `App.TableView`.

```
{{view App.TableView contentBinding=content}}
```

The setup of the tableData also belongs in a `model()` hook. It works in the sample because `tableData` variable is in scope.

Here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDkqG/1/).

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish here is to have the TableView as an independent component, which can be used any where in the app, so it needs to have its own controller. Without any controller binding, the controller is set to whoever is showing the view, in this case the ApplicationController.  So the issue is if I have a different controller for the view as in example on [Ember Guide -View Context](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html), then using itemController gives problem.     How can I have a seperate controller for the view ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction : use of Needs. Solved it by putting the TableViewContainer in needs and then binding it as controllerBinding="controllers.tableView". Then it works fine with item controllers. Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akashb/wEprA/3/). although I still think this could be a bug. Maybe somebody from Ember team can look into this.